# Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread using "getcurrentsession" but works fine with "opensession"?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am new to spring mvc and Hibernate I am trying to create an sample login application using spring mvc and hibernate, but while running the following code of line :

```
session=this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

I am getting following error:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014)
    at com.peddle.repository.UserProfileRepositoryImpl.getuserByName(UserProfileRepositoryImpl.java:46)
```

This error can be handeled if i use "opensession" in place of "get currentsession". But I would like to know what is the config details I am doing wrong due to which I am unable to get current session using hibernate.

Following are the code and config file details:

1] Spring servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

<!-- bean JSP view resolver here -->    
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.package" />    
    <mvc:annotation-driven />       
<!--  List of Bean classes used -->         
</beans>
```

2] DB-Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>classpath:database.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class ">thread</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor">org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor
                </prop>
            </props>
        </property>
<!--  Mapping all @entity classes to table -->
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.entity" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="transactionInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="transactionAttributeSource">
            <value>
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

3] Web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Peddle Customer</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml, /WEB-INF/DBConfig.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
                  org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
                </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

4] Service Layer

```
@Service
class Services
{
      @Transactional
    @Override
    public UserCustomer getuserByName(UserDetails userDetails) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return userProfileRepository.getuserByName(userDetails);
    }
}
```

5] Repository layer

```
@Repository
public class UserProfileRepositoryImpl
{
      @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;
   Transaction transaction = null;
    Session session = null;

     @Override
    public UserCustomer getuserByName(UserDetails userDetails){
        UserCustomer Usercustomer=null;
        try {
            session=this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
             // related implementation here
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return Usercustomer;
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is ridiculously long, consider editing please.. You can start by posting only the relevant parts.

Comment: @Taslim I have deleted most of unnecessary code as per your advice.

Comment: @srik123 I recommend stripping it down as far as you can go and still reproduce the problem. That's what the SO rules mean by [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Often people find their problem themselves just by going through the exercise of stripping the code down.

Answer (score 0):

OpenSession always open new brand session and the current-session doesn't.

**OpenSession:**

When you call SessionFactory.openSession, it always create new Session object afresh and give it to you. You need to explicitly flush and close these session objects. As session objects are not thread safe, you need to create one session object per request in multithreaded environment and one session per request in web applications too.

**CurrentSession:**

When you call SessionFactory. getCurrentSession, it will provide you session object which is in hibernate context and managed by hibernate internally. It is bound to transaction scope.
When you call SessionFactory. getCurrentSession , it creates a new Session if not exists , else use same session which is in current hibernate context. It automatically flush and close session when transaction ends, so you do not need to do externally.
If you are using hibernate in single threaded environment , you can use getCurrentSession, as it is faster in performance as compare to creating  new session each time.